# 3-clause BSD + Apache License 2.0 + Mozilla Public License 1.1

Tags: open-source-software

I'm currently handling a project where devolopers have used the 3 different oss codes & respective licenses abovementioned and also proprietary code.
scenario is as follows:

- The sw tool being developed will use the oss code (set of libraries) without modifications;
- The libraries will be used in binary form;
- Proprietary source code is not intermixed with libraries code; but
- It calls the use of the api of the libraries.

I know that Apache 2.0 and Mozilla 1.1 are incompatible. Since i can also apply Mozilla's 2.0 license terms this makes all these different licenses compatible with each other?

Getting to the question: what license terms should prevail? or is the correct way to distribute the sw tool to do it including a ABOUT file with all the different license terms?

Comment: Wait, there are proprietary libraries that are used?

Comment: no, the proprietary code will call the use of api of the oss libraries.

Comment: @Zizouz212, can you help?

Comment: So the resultant program is one that is proprietary?

Comment: that's actually implicit in my question. does calling the use of api libraries forces me to apply those license terms? or can I just simply distribute tose licenses with the respective license terms in the same package and keep the code proprietary?

Answer (score 1):

I'm neglecting any proprietary terms that may affect your program.

Since you don't modify any code or binaries of the open source projects...

- BSD licensed code: Make sure to attribute, display license notice;
- Apache 2.0 code: Make sure to attribute, display license notice;
- Mozilla 2.0 code: No changes, make sure to attribute, display license notice.

So basically, nothing "prevails."

What you need to do in your application is assure that you provide all projects with the attribution they require, through displaying the license notices.